# How to get the dropdownlistselectedid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
var countries = context.MasterCountries.ToList();
ddlcountry.DataSource = countries;
ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Description";
ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlcountry.DataBind();

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlcountry" CssClass="textbox textbox-reg" />

int countryid = ddlcountry.SelectedIndex;
```

I am trying to get the id of the company but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
int countryid = int.Parse(ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
```